# Legacy Webcam + Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, webcam

Recently I migrated my desktop computer from Windows 7 to Ubuntu. I can't make it recognize WebCam (Creative PD1001).

There's no stock driver, I but found [this sourceforge project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/epcam/) which supports my device.

I thought it was going to be a quick fix, but nope.

- Ungzipped the archives
- Followed the instructions

And now I'm receiving lots of errors from gcc (i guess)

Here's a screenshot, after some seconds of waiting... this is the output of `make`:

[image]

"virhe" in Finnish means "error"

Comment: what is the output of `uname -r` ?

Comment: "4.2.0-35-generic" seems like I'm running the newest kernel build

Comment: just as i thought, well in the comment block of the c file of that driver stands it is tested to run with 3.18.9, thats the last change made. I#m actually trying to figure out a way so you can compile this.

Comment: any chance you know the used chipset of your usb webcam? Because Creative build this webcam with 2 different chipsets (EP800 or OV518).

Answer (score 0):

I now found out after around 2 hours of trying and searching through the depths of www, that the support for v4l1 was dropped in recent kernels. And despite my effords to rewrite the code to use v4l2 header files it won't compile.

So best get a newer webcam to use.